# Changing function name every time script runs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop running in a script, and in that for loop there is a function, `def OpenButton():`, which triggers when a tkinter button is pressed (although this has nothing to do with tkinter). I need the name of the def script to have a different string at the end, every time the for loops runs.

Example: First loop: `def OpenButtonString1():` but the second time it runs to be `def OpenButtonString2():` (They would be actual strings, not `def OpenButtonString` increasing number `():`, but I can't figure it out, since using `exec('def OpenButton' + StringName + '():')` doesn't actually detect the indented lines under as something part of the function.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? You seem to have decided on one particular solution and are trying to get that to work, but we may be able to help you come up with a better solution. To start with, why do the functions have to be named something different each time? What do you expect to gain from being able to do that?

Comment: basically, the script I tried to make a different name for the function, wasn't allowing me to actually put anything in that function

Comment: Why do you need a script that is giving it a different name each time?

Comment: I have a script that gets the name of everything in a folder, and im now using tkinter, so I wanted a feature to go to that folder, but its creating the same button every time, but I have a variable that has the name, so I need different functions to seperate all the buttons

Comment: and if I name them with different things at the end, and join that with an exec function, it would work, but I cant get the function to be named differently

Comment: so basically I just need to figure out how to insert a variable into a function name

Comment: " I need the name of the def script to have a different string at the end, every time the for loops runs." You really need to elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do, ideally, providing a [mcve]

Comment: So, you shouldn't be using `exec` here in the first place. You basically want to dynamically name a button in tkinter. That is straightforward and doesn't require `exec`, just elaborate on what you are trying to do exactly (showing the code!)

Comment: See [Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) (it applies to function names, too).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a function that returns functions. The name of a function isn't really that important.

```
>>> def function_creator(foo):
...     def dynamic_function():
...             print(foo)
...     return dynamic_function
... 
>>> func1 = function_creator('Hello')
>>> func2 = function_creator('World')
>>> func1()
Hello
>>> func2()
World
```

You can store the functions just like any other variable, like putting them in a list or dictionary. Also, as you can see in my example, you can pass whatever information you need into your function creator and the function it creates can use the info upon being called.